# Template function not instantiating/receiving call using rvalue reference

Tags: c++

As stated in the title, when I explicitly instantiate an lvalue and an rvalue version of a function it works, if I try to do so using templates it does not. gcc 7.4. What am I missing?

```
class Test {};

class Explicit {
public:
    void func (const Test &t) {
        cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<const Test&>::value << endl;
    }

    void func (Test &&t) {
        cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<Test&&>::value << endl;
    }
};

class Implicit {
public:
    template<class T>
    void func (T t) {
        cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << endl;
    }
};

// explicitly instantiate two versions of the function
template void Implicit::func<const Test &> (const Test &);
template void Implicit::func<Test &&> (Test &&);

int main () {
    Explicit e = Explicit ();
    Implicit i = Implicit ();
    Test t;

    e.func (t);                 // goes to func (const Test&), as expected
    e.func (Test ());           // goes to func (Test&&), as expected
    e.func ((Test &&) Test ()); // goes to func (Test&&), as expected

    i.func (t);                 // goes to func (const Test&), as expected
    i.func (Test ());           // goes to func (const Test&), not as expected!
    i.func ((Test &&) Test ()); // goes to func (const Test&), not as expected!
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision *may* be relevant.

Comment: Here's [an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72d554db0bd7a160) that shows better what's really going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your explicit instantiations are useless (Might be useful when you split header and cpp):

```
// explicitly instantiate two versions of the functions
template void Implicit::func<const Test &> (const Test &);
template void Implicit::func<Test &&> (Test &&);
```

For your "Implicit", you got in fact:

```
i.func (t);                 // goes to func(Test)
i.func (Test ());           // goes to func(Test)
i.func ((Test &&) Test ()); // goes to func(Test)
```

as

```
template<class T> void func (T t)
```

doesn't deduce references.

You call then `void Implicit::func<Test>`.